# How to trace bitmap with perfect shapes?

Tags: inkscape, image-trace

I'm quite beginner in Inkscape and wish to redraw this not-so-simple (at least for me) bitmap:

[image]

Shadows are nice to have, but not required.

I tried with trace tool:

[image]

The result is this:

[image]

While this is not that bad, I wish to get a more perfect shapes (with less points):

Zooming in to the left part, you can see it's very unsymmetric:

[image]

And also contains massive amount of points:

[image]

Although I know I can redraw this from scratch, but it's quite complicated. Is there any faster way to reproduce this bitmap with symmetric (and asymmetric where needed: right side) shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today the tracing programs have not reached the dumbness level of Dall-E, ChatGPT, Stable Diffusion etc... so they try to guess in a simple way what your noisy and blurry original might contain. The programs follow their programmed rules which do not try to make further guesses based on all available internet content. You even have no place to input "Only perfect curves for me, please!".

You must either trace it manually to get what you want or edit the automatic tracing result. Here's one result and few edits:

[image]

On the top there's your original. The 2nd is the raw tracing result. It was got with the default brightness treshold and edge smoothing. The original already is highly asymmetric even in the left half. But Inkscape is not programmed to care.

In the 3rd version the hole is changed to a shape. The hole comes from a combined path. It's broken apart, the group is ungrouped and the outer rectangle is deleted. This is what remained.

The 4th version has no fill, a black stroke is inserted

In the 5th version a few vertical lines are inserted manually to show one possibility to insert manually some details you might want. The new lines have round ends and they start and end at the centerline of the edge stroke. They snap well automatically if you draw them by clicking only with the pen, hold Ctrl as you draw and have snaps ON.

If the left half must be symmetric you can split the curve and duplicate & flip the part which should be symmetric. Here's a couple of screenshots which show the achieved vertical symmetry. The flipped implant is selected:

[image]

[image]

Probably you want to remake some finer details, too. I skip it.

You can insert gradient colors if you make at first colorizable closed areas. The shape builder in current Inkscape is the perfect tool for making them.

Late addition: As you can see, some high reputation members would draw this shape manually either by doing it from scratch or by tracing it manually i.e. drawing on your original. They wouldn't waste a second to clean the inaccuracies of the automatic tracing result. That's no problem for persons who have years or decades ago climbed up the learning curve of drawing and editing Bezier curves. Aim the same. This shape is so simple that working 1...2 days through some Bezier curve drawing and editing tutorials makes you wonder "How in the hell I didn't start by tracing it manually".

Answer (score 2):

Any auto-tracing tool/feature is like a fax machine... it sees merely white (or transparent) pixels and colored pixels. None of them know that something is meant to be a straight, let alone symmetrical, line.

You can try various tools/applications and some may work better than others for a particular raster image.

You can try increasing the dimensions of the original raster image before tracing. This *may* lead to better results.

Ultimately tracings are what they are. Tweaking settings for the tracing can help in some instances, but not always. A great deal is highly dependent upon the original image in terms of size, contrast, etc.

The reality is auto-tracing is meant to be a *first step* in the conversion process, not necessarily the final step. The more accurate you want the final vector, the more manual alterations/adjustments you need to be prepared to make.

In *many* instances *manually* tracing something can yield *much, much* better results than any auto-tracing ever will.

For me, personally, I would not even consider auto-tracing for such a rudimentary shape. Manually tracing it would allow me to simply use a single stroke and set a stroke weight. And, since it's done manually, symmetry would be easy... draw half, reflect, connect.

Answer (score 1):

Auto tracing that image will never result in anything perfect. The image is quite poor quality and quite low resolution.  You might want to consider manually tracing it if you want something perfect. The shape is not massively complex, and would be fairly easy.

A quick example of a small portion of the image redrawn manually

[image]

Comment: Wow. How did you redraw this manually?

Comment: @Daniel I made rectangles with rounded corners, also used the pen tool for other parts, and union boolean operations to merge all the shapes.